# Cache-Control Optimization in Meta and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, meta-tags, cache-control

We want to learn and optimize caching for our website, and we have the following codes.

In meta, we have:

For pages 1-10,

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=2592000, public">
```

For pages 11-20,

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=604800, private">
```

For pages 21-25,

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=3600, private">
```

For pages 26-28,

```
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

In .htaccess file:

```
#### Expires By Type
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 60 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 29030400 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

#### Cache-Control
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php|xml)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#### ETags
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
```

This is a response we received for page 1 from [redbot.org](http://redbot.org),

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 14:14:50 GMT
    Server: Apache
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.17
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-
        check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Cache-Control: max-age=600, private, must-revalidate
    Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT
    Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

1. Do you think `Header unset ETag` in the .htaccess file would be
   necessary?
2. I'm not sure why we would get `Pragma: no-cache` for page
   1 in the response since we have `<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=2592000, public">` for page 1.
3. Is there anything we are doing wrong, and could be optimized/changed in better ways?
4. Is it necessary to have both `image/jpeg` and `image/jpg` in the ExpriesByTyps. Any other comments is appreciated.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Ad 2) – there is a difference between _real_ HTTP response headers, and `meta http-equiv` – and the first ones have precedence.